# Why is W3C HTML Validator giving me an error on <body>?

Tags: html

I don't understand why it's giving me this error:

***Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.***

I don't see why this is happening, because it works when I load the site on my browser.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Globo.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>



        <header>
            <img class="quadrados" src="https://via.placeholder.com/44" alt="">
            <h1 class="menu">Menu</h1>
            <h1 class="email">Email V</h1>
            <h1 class="titulo">Globo.com</h1>
            <img class="lupa" src="https://via.placeholder.com/44" alt="">
            <h1 class="busca">Busca</h1>
            <img class="boneco" src="https://via.placeholder.com/44" alt="">
            <h1 class="conta">Conta Globo</h1>
        </header>

        <header class="pequenos">
            <h1>g1</h1>
            <h1>o globo</h1>
            <h1>valor</h1>
            <h1>ge</h1>
            <h1>cartola</h1>
            <h1>globoplay</h1>
            <h1>dropz</h1>
            <h1>gshow</h1>
            <h1>quem</h1>
            <h1>receitas</h1>
        </header>
    <body>
        <h2>Vacinação de Jovens</h2>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: All html elements (eg your `header`s) need to be inside the body tag otherwise one will be created automatically (therefore you have two which is invalid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `header` tag outside of your `body`. In order to have valid HTML page, **all elements** such as `divs`, `nav`, `header` etc.. should be placed inside the `body` tag. Hence your HTML code is invalid according to the W3 validator.

The following code should be valid according to the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). Note the order the code has been written:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Globo.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>    
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="quadrados" src="https://via.placeholder.com/44" alt="">
        <h1 class="menu">Menu</h1>
        <h1 class="email">Email V</h1>
        <h1 class="titulo">Globo.com</h1>
        <img class="lupa" src="https://via.placeholder.com/44" alt="">
        <h1 class="busca">Busca</h1>
        <img class="boneco" src="https://via.placeholder.com/44" alt="">
        <h1 class="conta">Conta Globo</h1>
    </header>

    <header class="pequenos">
        <h1>g1</h1>
        <h1>o globo</h1>
        <h1>valor</h1>
        <h1>ge</h1>
        <h1>cartola</h1>
        <h1>globoplay</h1>
        <h1>dropz</h1>
        <h1>gshow</h1>
        <h1>quem</h1>
        <h1>receitas</h1>
    </header>
    <h2>Vacinação de Jovens</h2>
</body>
</html>
```